# Is "must have four cats" the same as "must have got four cats"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, modal-verbs

On Cambridge Online Dictionary, the phrase "have got" is considered a formal alternative to simply "have", for example:

> He has four cats.

> He has got four cats.

I want to ask: Does adding an additional modal verb (e.g. *must*) change the meaning, or is the meaning of "must have got" & "must have" still the same?

In other words, do these sentences mean the same thing?:

> He must have four cats.

> He must have got four cats.

How about with modals apart from *must*?

Comment: I think you will find that the dictionary describes _have got_ as _informal_. I would say that _must have got_ is possible, but a speaker would be much less likely to add _got_ when using _must have_.

Comment: First, there is no modal auxiliary in your examples. The reverse of what you say is true. "Have got" is restricted to informal style, though it is very common, especially in BrE. Other than that, there's no difference in meaning between your two examples, at least not in BrE.

Comment: @BillJ I think what the OP's asking seems to be: "Do *must have got* and *must have* mean the same thing? Or does the addition of *must* constrict our interpretation of *have got*? I think it does. It's hard for me to think of a situation where I'd interpret *must have got a cat*, for example, to mean the same thing as *must have a cat*.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Now that you mention it, neither can I. I’ve reöpened the question upon that consideration.

Comment: I can't see any real difference between _They must have a cat_ and _They must have got a cat_. Where it expresses a state rather than an event, of course. .

Comment: @BillJ The difference is that although "they have got a cat" is an alternative stative "they must have got a cat" is not stative (in Br English anyway). If you say "They must have got a cat" the sentence definitely refers to a recent event. If, as a person who is allergic to cats, I can walk into a house I've never been in, feel the itching and say "They must have a cat". However I would only say "They must have _got_ a cat" if I walked into a house I'd been in before and never felt the itch but this time I get the itch because they must have acquired a cat recently.

Comment: @BoldBen "They must have got a cat" can certainly refer to a state, which is why it's an idiom, used in informal speech, mainly in BrE. The non-idiomatic sense means "have obtained", which isn't applicable here.  In other words, stative "have" (i.e expressing possession) is replaceable by the informal idiom "have got", especially in BrE. It takes an NP object, as in "She has got a swimming pool", which means the same as "She has a swimming pool". Admittedly, though, it occurs  predominantly in the present tense, the plain form being less common.

Answer (score 1):

**I have 4 cats.** = I currently own/am in charge of/possess 4 cats

**I have got 4 cats.** (British English) = (i) I have [very recently] received/bought/obtained, etc, 4 cats (ii) I currently possess 4 cats

(i) is more distinct in American English but the past participle is "gotten" - I have **gotten** 4 cats. This does not have the meaning of (ii).

Comment: I wanna specify, my question is, given that we know "have got" & "have" are the same, can we base upon that to say that "must have got" & "must have" are the same as well.

Comment: Right, here *I’ve got three letters in my name* is mere ongoing possession, whereas *I’ve gotten three letters from them already* means the postman delivered them to you or whatnot.

Comment: @tchrist I think the OP's main concern is about the modal *must* (in relation to *have got*).

Comment: Then there's "I went hunting in Africa.  I got four cats."